# How to handle API request that does not throw catch? (403 error)

Tags: javascript, react-native, azure-blob-storage

Tried to access blob storage API with the following method but getting 403 return without error throw(this happen because I'm trying to access file that does not exist/no permission). How should such error be handled?  `.catch` is already applied while calling the API.

**Background**..
I'm trying to make mistake by purpose to get a file inside Azure blob storage. I do expect 403 and I wish to handle this properly.

**Get method**

```
 getReq = async url => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          reject(error);
        })
    });
  };
```

**Response received from postman**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:maskedInfo
Time:maskedInfo</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was 


/blob/maskedInfo/maskedInfo/maskedInfo.json
ReadOnly


2020-08-04
b





</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

**Tried:**

1. `TryCatch` does not catch the issue either

**Error show from React Native:**
[image]

Comment: How do you call `getReq()` method?

Comment: @BadPiggie usual `async` `await` style, not sure what you're trying to undrestand.

Comment: Show the code how you invoke the method `getReq()`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `getReq()` method, It will return a `Promise`. So, You should handle the rejection.

```
getReq("https://somerandomurl.com")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
```

**In await style,**

```
try {
  const res = await getReq("https://somerandomurl.com");
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```